# Selecting items in an ordered list after a certain entry

Tags: c#, linq

I have an ordered list of objects. I can easily find an item in the list by using the following code:

```
purchaseOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OurRef.Equals(lastPurchaseOrder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

What I want to do is select all the items in the list that appear after this entry. How best to achieve this? Would it to be to get the index of this item and select a range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile):

```
var orders = purchaseOrders.SkipWhile(x => !x.OurRef.Equals(...));
```

Once the iterator has stopped skipping, it doesn't evaluate the predicate for later entries.

Note that that code will *include* the entry that doesn't match the predicate, i.e. the one with the given reference. It will basically give you all entries from that order onwards. You can always use `.Skip(1)` if you want to skip that:

```
// Skip the exact match
var orders = purchaseOrders.SkipWhile(x => !x.OurRef.Equals(...)).Skip(1);
```

This will be linear, mind you... if the list is ordered by `x.OurRef` you could find the index with a binary search and take the range from there onwards... but I wouldn't do that unless you find that the simpler code causes you problems.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should take a look at LINQ's combination of Reverse and TakeWhile methods, if I understand your question correctly.

It may look like `purchaseOrder.Reverse().TakeWhile(x => !x.OurRef.Equals(lastPurchaseOrder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`.

Sorry if code is unformatted, I'm from mobile web right now.

Comment: I don't think `TakeWhile` makes sense here, but if you think it does please put an example of how the OP can use it.

Comment: @juharr 'purchaseOrder.Reverse().TakeWhile(x => !x.OurRef.Equals(lastPurchaseOrder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))' will return objects that were after entry due to reversed order of source. (Sorry for unformatted, i'm on mobile web right now.)

Comment: You should add that to the answer and just to make sure the order is the same as the original add another `Reverse` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this:

```
int itemIndex = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OurRef.Equals(lastPurchaseOrder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
var newList = list.Where((f, i) => i >= itemIndex);
```

Comment: `Where` has an overload that includes the index in the predicate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx